# How do I overwrite Data Annotations using N-Tier Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, data-annotations, n-tier-architecture

I have a string property that is required, but I need to accommodate an empty string; currently my [Required] data annotation raises an error on an empty string.  The data annotation I need is [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)], but the [Required] data annotation is on the entity generated file, which I cannot modify.  I tried adding the [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)] to the property on the corresponding .metadata.cs file, but I still get an error with an empty string.  What would you advise?

Comment: Do you have to *save* empty strings, or just allow them without saving?

Comment: I just need to allow them, I do not want to save them.

Comment: Why can't you change the generated file? It's just a .tt somewhere.

Comment: Then just use a DTO or view model with different validation.

Comment: I can't change the generated file because it will be re-generated many times.  There is no way to modify the .tt file to adjust one attribute on one property since the .tt file creates all entities the same.

Comment: What I am doing is using a DataContext.EntitySet to bind to a combo control, and I want to add a blank selection option. So I want to add an entity with an empty string for the display member to the EntitySet, but that property is required and raises an error even though I'm not trying to save it.

Comment: @ChristofSenn Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of overriding data annotations. However, I see several alternative options for this case:

1. Turn-off validation on exceptions on the WPF data binding:

   {Binding Path=..., ValidatesOnExceptions=false}
2. Turn-off automatic data validation on data context, entity set, or entity level:

   dataContext.MyEntitySet.IsValidationEnabled = false
3. Modify tt file (T4\NTierEF.EntityTT.CS.ttinclude). A more advanced scenario would be to create a custom property for the edmx designer to define this annotation setting in the edmx and then take it into account in code generation.